# History of terrorist organizations designations/undesignations by Israel

Tags: law, government, israel, terrorism

In 1948, Israel passed the [Prevention of Terrorism Ordinance](http://www.mfa.gov.il/MFA/MFAArchive/1900_1949/Prevention+of+Terrorism+Ordinance+No+33+of+5708-19.htm), which allows it to officially designate organizations as terrorists in the Official Gazette.

What organizations have been designated this way and why?
What organizations have been "unlisted" from it and why?

*(My goal is to complete [the Wikipedia article about organizations officially designated as terrorists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_designated_terrorist_organizations))*

Comment: have --> were ?

Comment: @RickyDemer: Thanks! I had forgotten a word indeed.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul This is an interesting question, but can you reformat it to better conform with the guidelines of the faq: http://history.stackexchange.com/faq As it stands right now this question seems to be searching for reference material, and not necessarily concerned with say the history of classifying terrorist organizations.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I added the why to your questions, because without that it was probably a little too close to just a straight reference question. If you think it is too far from the original scope of your question by all means change it back, and the community can decide if it is appropriate.

Comment: Isn't this trivial? Doesn't Israel publish this list?  Perhaps I'm missing something, but isn't this a little like asking what stories are on the front page of the New York Times?  (it would be easier to consult the New York Times than to ask H:SE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have a lot of work. There are hundreds.

[The full list](http://www.mod.gov.il/Defence-and-Security/Fighting_terrorism/Documents/%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%A7%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%20terror%20-%20%207-7-2015.xls) is published by the Israeli ministry of justice and its in Hebrew(also include those which remarked as unlisted).

- *Please note that not all the organisations titled as terror groups. Some of them titled as "Unlawful Association" and some other titles. Those are not active terror groups but recognized as passive/active supporters(This is my interpretation)*.
- *It seems that since 2008 organisations that supported financially terror groups could be titled as 'terror group'. I assume that you won't consider them as 'classic' terror groups(They don't execute terror activity by themselves, but finance this kind of acts)*.

**Bottom line:** 
If you are looking to see all the organisations which are outlaw in Israel according the law of Prevention of Terrorism Ordinance This is the full list.

If you are trying to find which of them is actual terror group in its classic definition, you still have a lot of work to filter them out from this list.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks! Are all 372 organizations in this list designated as terrorist groups by Israel? For instance I see some banks and energy companies, maybe some of them are officially designated as "linked to terrorist organizations" rather than terrorist organizations themselves? Unfortunately I don't read Hebrew, is there a column defining the category? For instance when מהות ההכרזה/צו says צו תפיסה I guess it is just a seizure order rather than a designation as a terrorist group?

Comment: Column B: Name in Hebrew and, Column C: Name in English, Column D: Transliteration from Arabic to Hebrew letters, column E: Essence of declaration(Terror group. unlawful organisation etc.)